# SQL: How can I pick a cell value from one table as a condition to select another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Hi I'm a new learner of SQL. How can I realize this process in SQL or perhaps with python if needed:

First, from table1, I randomly selected two results:

```
SELECT TOP 2 id, date 
FROM table 1
WHERE date >= 2 AND date <= 6
ORDER BY RAND(CHECKSUM(*) * RAND())

+-----------+                      
|  table1   |                      
+-----------+                      
| id | date | 
+----+------+
| x  |  3   | 
| y  |  4   |  
+----+------+
```

I need to use the value `x` and `y` as conditions to display another table. For instance, using `x`, I can:

```
SELECT id, date 
FROM table1
WHERE date >= 2 AND date <= 6 AND id = 'x'
ORDER BY date ASC

+-----------+                      
|  table2   |                      
+-----------+                      
| id | date | 
+----+------+
| x  |  3   |
| x  |  4   |  
| x  |  5   |  
| x  |  6   |  
| x  |  6   |  
+----+------+
```

What I need is to get the length of table2 without duplication on date. For instance, table2 has 5 rows, but last two duplicate in date. So the final answer is `4 rows`.

For `id = y`, I have to do the same thing (say table3) and compare the length of table3 and table2 to see if consistent.

If yes, then return the length (say, 4 rows); If no, then go back to table1 and select another two id (say, z and y).

I was thinking to use python to select value or create variables, then use python variables in SQL. But it is too much for a new learner. I really appreciate it if someone could help me out this process.

Comment: Your description is somewhat confusing - are you wanting a count (or distinct count) or actual data? what does a date of `3` or `4` mean?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I want a number. The number is the length of table2/table3 (I need to make sure the lengths of two tables are the same). `date` is just a column name. You can think about it as Value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subqueries with IN clause

Here is too a Version with two diemsnions, maybe this will help also

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 ([id] varchar(2),[date] int)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
>     SELECT id, date FROM table1
>
>     where date >= 2 and date <= 6
>
>     and id IN (
>
>     SELECT TOP 2 id FROM table1
>
>     WHERE date >= 2 and date <= 6
>
>     ORDER BY RAND(CHECKSUM(*) * RAND())
> )
>
>     ORDER BY date ASC
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date
> :- | ---:
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id, date FROM table1
> WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
>               FROM (
>
>     SELECT TOP 2 id,[date] FROM table1
>
>     WHERE date >= 2 and date <= 6
>
>     ORDER BY RAND(CHECKSUM(*) * RAND())) AS table2
>               WHERE  table1.[id] = table2.[id]
>                         AND table1.[date] = table2.[date])
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date
> :- | ---:
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=62f58ff714ba0070f6db6556f3314a01)*

Comment: Thanks but I can't create new tables in the database. It is not permitted. Do you have other ideas? Appreciate!

Comment: you don't need to  create you can use the existing table for this.  I added a tbale only to show  that the qiery runs without problems

Comment: I think I can get some clues from your code and not create a new table. I will have a try! Thanks a lot!